# Passing through Spritenode

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, collision-detection, skspritenode

I have a hero/player, and i want him to be able to go through objects/obstacle, and when i does, delete the obstacles. that works fine, kind of.

I use this code for my obstacle

```
SKSpriteNode *Obstacle = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor blackColor] size:CGSizeMake(40, 40)];
Obstacle.name = @"speedBoost";
Obstacle.position = CGPointMake(self.ObstacleX + 100,0);
Obstacle.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody Obstacle.size];
Obstacle.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = ObstacleCategory;
Obstacle.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;
Obstacle.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
[self.world Obstacle];
```

So when my hero passes through the object from the sides, the obstacle is deleted and works fine
but when my hero passes through the obstacle from above or below the obstacle, the hero is stopped before the obstacle is deleted

how can I fix this?

thanks in advance

COLLISION

```
if ([firstBody.node.name isEqualToString:@"hero"] && [secondBody.node.name isEqualToString:@"obstacle"]) {
    [self obstacle];
}
```

Comment: what is the collisionBitMask of your hero

Comment: How are you detecting contacts? The obstacle's physicsBody is not dynamic...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so you've got the BitMasks set up so that's a start.

**To see whether something has had a contact:**

1. make sure that the scene has the `<SKPhysicsContactDelegate>` in front of interface
2. use `didBeginContact` method to see if a collision has occurred
3. set up bitMasks likewise:

   - CategoryBitMask - identifies the object, other object's contactTest and collision bitMasks match up to it
   - ContactTestBitMask - will call didBeginContact if categoryBitMask of object in collision matches to this
   - CollisionBitMask - what it collides with

so just set those the right way and use bit-wise operators inside of `didBeginContact` to test...